# Implementing underlined header and footer while printing Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextpane

I am creating a program that prints a multipage document with underlined header and footer. My document is in a JTextPane. The print method of JComponent class is:

```
JTextComponent.print(MessageFormat headerFormat, MessageFormat footerFormat, 
boolean showPrintDialog, PrintService service, PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes,
boolean interactive)
```

prints my document along with a header and footer passed as headerFormat and footerFormat response. However I need to underline the header and footer along with changing its font size.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

See http://java-sl.com/articles.html 4 articles about printing of JTextPane with custom header and footer. The [article](http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane_HF.html) about headers and footers.

Alternatively you can try [this](http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html) one to print/preview content. It would require custom header/footer implementation but also it's possibly.

Comment: I have gone through with these articles. APIs are very good but do not solve my purpose. I need header/footer be added only while printing. I do not need to show user any frame asking for header and footer.